# Is it possible for me to change the formatting buttons in the Matrix rich text field?

Tags: rte

Is it possible for me to change the formatting buttons in the Matrix rich text field? Just trying to add a break tag `<br>` and maybe a couple others.

Comment: The formatting buttons aren't part of Matrix. They are part of the ExpressionEngine native RTE. Please see the docs for how to adjust settings for the RTE field: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/rte/control_panel/index.html

Comment: @JeremyGimbel Can you move you comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The formatting buttons aren't part of Matrix. They are part of the ExpressionEngine native RTE. Please see the docs for how to adjust settings for the RTE field [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/rte/control_panel/index.html).